# How to break for loop inside Cypress's then() function?

Tags: javascript, loops, automated-tests, cypress, break

I want to break for loop if `.contacts` element's style doen't equal `display: none`, but I can't find a way to do this inside then() fuction.

Use case: I want to click through table elements until contacts panel appears and then fill contacts. But if I don't stop the loop after panel appears it will disappear and I will get an error.

```
        cy.get('@count').then($count => {
            for (let i = 1; i <= $count - 1; i++) {
                if (i == 1) {
                    cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .room-type`).eq(1).click()
                }
                else {
                    cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .room-type`).click()
                }
                cy.get('.spinner').should('not.exist')

                cy.get('.contacts').then($contacts => {
                    if ($contacts.attr('style') != 'display: none;') {
                        //I want to break the loop here if condition is met
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Comment: The loop is setting up the promises and once you'll enter the `then` callbacks, the setup is already done. In other words you try to mix synchronous with asynchronous behaviour which is not going to act as you expect.
Maybe by nesting even more your code you'll achieve what you need.

Comment: @MetallimaX If I nest for loop inside contacts' `then()` it would not enter if condition where I want to break the loop, because it would save `style` atribute when it was `'display: none;'`. 
The code above successfully enters `if` condition, but I can't break the loop, nor return any values from there

Comment: `then` means I promiss to answer but it isn't executed at the same time it is setup. The loop may have finished once your `then` callback is called. What you need is a synchronous behaviour and you try to obtain it with an asynchronous framework. This will not work.

Comment: @Ackroydd it's not always that I need to cycle through the full loop. As I mentioned in the question, sometimes I need to break the loop early if the condition is met

Comment: @VladimirKrygin you might be able to break the loop by setting the loop counter above to it's max, that is add `i = $count`  where you have the comment `//I want to break the loop here`

Comment: @Ackroydd I tried that. For some reason I got weird result:
if I don't log `i` loop won't stop at all. If I try and log `i` inside if statement I would get `i is not defined`

Comment: Yeah, my mistake - it's mix of sync and async code  - the loop runs faster than `cy.get('.contacts').then(...` resolves. You might get away with using `const $contacts = Cypress.$('.contacts'); if ($contacts.attr(...` - but it looks more and more messy.

Comment: This sounds semantically like a use-case for [cypress-wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-wait-until), but the docs are a bit thin, cannot tell if it handles your case. Internally that lib uses recursion instead of iteration - so maybe a better pattern for you.

Comment: BTW `i is not defined` makes no sense - javascript supports closure, the loop variable `i` should be available everywhere inside the for block.

Comment: @Ackroydd thanks for advice. Using cypress' jquery didn't seem to make much of an effect. cypress-wait-until just started another loop inside my loop and then timed out with the error message `Timed out retrying`.
I guess it's not possible for now to perform such GUI testing with cypress, so I came up with another solution using api requests to make sure contacts panel appears

Comment: You would use `cypress-wait-until` ***instead*** of the loop, not inside it.

Comment: @Ackroydd I can't quite understand how to replace for loop with wait until

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way to go about about is the recursive approach. Using recursive approach your problem of synchronous and Asynchronous code will be resolved automatically.
So you can approach this problem with something like this below. The below code might not work as it is, you may have to do some changes accordingly. The main Idea is try going recursive approach if you want to avoid the sync-async code problem

```
cy.get("@count").then(($count) => {
    test_recusive($count);
});

export const test_recusive = (count) => {
if (i == 1) {
    cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .room-type`).eq(1).click();
} else {
    cy.get(`:nth-child(${i}) > .room-type`).click();
}
cy.get(".spinner").should("not.exist");

cy.get(".contacts").then(($contacts) => {
    if ($contacts.attr("style") != "display: none;") {
        //I want to break the loop here if condition is met
        return;
    } else {
        return test_recusive(count - 1);
    }
});
```

Now all the calls in your code will be synchronous ones.